# Ler JSON e imprimir no html com angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Estou tentando imprimir os dados de um arquivo JSON no html usando AngularJS, rodando tudo pelo XAMPP e na minha pasta htdocs/teste tem 3 arquivos (index.html, main.js, teste.json). O console não mostra nenhum erro, tentei inclusive debugar pelo firefox, coloquei um breakpoint no $http.get, mas nunca chega nesse ponto. Segue o código JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('teste.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = response;
    });
});
```

JSON:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"John"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Paul"}] </br/>
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in myData">
        {{data.id}}
        {{data.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Na aba de network no developer tools o http é corrido?

Comment: Recebe status 200, então imagino que sim Sergio

Comment: Não entendo muito de angular, mas até onde sei tem, precisa definir os services que faz as requisições ajax e consegue enviar para a controller com os $scope's

Comment: @clr19 dá para vêr a resposta desse 200 também?

Comment: Interessante está recebendo o status 200 mas não está parando no breakpoint

Comment: Não consegui ver a resposta do 200, mas realmente acho estranho não parar no breakpoint, não consigo imaginar qual seria o problema.

Comment: Se este é seu HTML completo, não irá funcionar porque em momento algum você declara o início da aplicação Angular (com ng-app.)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta da requisição, injetada na variável **response**, não contém a lista de valores que você espera. Segundo a documentação disponível em https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Sendo assim, acredito que seu *controller* deveria ser assim:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('teste.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
});
```

Se preferir, utilize **console.log** para verificar a resposta:

```
console.log(response);
```